# Segmentation fault in ARM assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm using the as assembler and the ld linker. My program assembles and links fine, but whenever I run it i get a segmentation fault message. my OS is Debian and I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 B

Here is my code:

```
.globl _start
MOV r0, #1
MOV r1, #1
ADD r0, r1
```

Comment: You forgot to end your program properly, e.g. by using an exit syscall. As it is, the cpu continues past your program and tries to execute random bytes as code which will fault sooner or later. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: ... and that's it? No `bx lr` (if that's `main`)? No call to the `exit` syscall? The processor is going to execute whatever follows in memory and do random stuff (or trap while trying to read instructions from an invalid page).

Comment: If you are using a debugger to step through your program you may see "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" before you reach the end of the segment; which is triggering Segmentation fault. Better yet, a debugger will let you see the random bytes that follow your code,  as @Jester indicated. The visual is very beneficial to the learning process, imho.

Comment: Couldn't edit last comment but in my case the "random" instruction that triggers the fault is ldrbtvc r7,  [r3].  r3 has a value of 0